# Tensorflow regression model doesn't learn from negative values

Tags: tensorflow

I use tensorflow for nontrivial regression problem. 
input of my network (array with 192 binary (0 or 1) elements) representing poker hand, poker bets and action and output (array with single element) representing gain from this action.
Network has 3 hidden layers with 100 neurons

```
    input_layer = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, self.INPUT_LAYER_SIZE))
    layer_1_biases = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(stddev=self.STD_DEV, shape=[self.LAYER_1_SIZE]))
    layer_1_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(stddev=self.STD_DEV, shape=[self.INPUT_LAYER_SIZE, self.LAYER_1_SIZE]))
    layer_2_biases = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(stddev=self.STD_DEV, shape=[self.LAYER_2_SIZE]))
    layer_2_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(stddev=self.STD_DEV, shape=[self.LAYER_1_SIZE, self.LAYER_2_SIZE]))
    layer_3_biases = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(stddev=self.STD_DEV, shape=[self.LAYER_3_SIZE]))
    layer_3_weights = tf.Variable(
        tf.truncated_normal(stddev=self.STD_DEV, shape=[self.LAYER_2_SIZE, self.LAYER_3_SIZE]))

    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(input_layer, layer_1_weights), layer_1_biases)
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, layer_2_weights), layer_2_biases)
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)
    layer_3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_2, layer_3_weights), layer_3_biases)
    layer_3 = tf.nn.relu(layer_3)

    output_layer_weights = tf.ones(shape=[self.LAYER_2_SIZE,1])
    output_layer = tf.matmul(layer3, output_layer_weights)

    return input_layer, output_layer
```

I try to minimize square error with learning rate 0.001 and GradientDescentOptimizer:

```
self._target = tf.placeholder("float", [None])
self.cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self._target - tf.transpose(self.output_layer)))
self._train_operation = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(self.LEARNING_RATE).minimize(self.cost)
```

As a result of training (100 iterations) I got for this target:

```
[-10.0, -10.0, -10.0, +10.0, -10.0]
```

this output  :

```
[0.08981139, 0.05091755, 0.04566674, 0.06034175, 9.99115811, 0.13543463]
```

I also didn't see any negative outputs in log files during training. So my network don't learn from negative values. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:
Activation function ReLU is: `max(0,x)` where `x` is weighted sum of inputs. So the function out always positive. You should use other activate function (like `tanh`)